# Media control bar always visible

Tags: c#, maui

I am developing a MAUI Shell application and would like to display a media control bar (at the top or bottom of the screen) which remains visible during navigation from page to page.

Do you have any ideas for this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to put your control on all pages of your app, you can create a `BasePage` as the parent of the pages for your app.

And if you want to put your control on the bottom or top of the pages, you can use `ContentPresenter` and `Grid` to achieve this.

A `ContentPresenter` can be placed in a control template to mark where content to be displayed by the templated custom control or templated page will appear. The custom control or page that consumes the control template will then define content to be displayed by the `ContentPresenter`.

You can refer to the following code:

**BasePage.xaml.cs**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiPopApp1229.BasePage"
             Title="BasePage">


    <ContentPage.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="80" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                 <!-- Content from child page   -->
                <ContentPresenter    BackgroundColor="Yellow"/>
                
                
                <!--  put your control here --> 
                <HorizontalStackLayout Grid.Row="1" BackgroundColor="Pink"  >
                   <Label  Text="Put your control here"  VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                </HorizontalStackLayout>

            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentPage.ControlTemplate>

</ContentPage>
```

**TestPage.xaml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?> 
<mauiapp:BasePage 
              xmlns:mauiapp="clr-namespace:MauiPopApp"
              xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
              xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="MauiPopApp.TestPage"
             Title="TestPage">
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label 
            Text="Welcome to child page!"
            VerticalOptions="Center" 
            HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</mauiapp:BasePage>
```

**TestPage.xaml.cs**

```
public partial class TestPage : BasePage
{
      public TestPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();
      }
}
```